# NET-SSH2 for perl 5.20.2 on windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, perl

I am trying to install NET-SSH2 for perl 5.20.2 on windows 2008r2 but no success.

C:\Perl>ppm install NET-SSH2
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...failed 500 Can't connect to ppm4.activestate.com:80
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides NET-SSH2

please help

Answer (score 0):

ActiveState has not gotten that package to build for that version of Perl, it seems.  The dependency on the libssh2 library is the problem.  See the build log here:

[ActiveState Perl 5.20 Net::SSH2 build log](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x64/5.20/2000/R/RK/RKITOVER/Net-SSH2-0.53.d/)

I believe [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) has libssh2 built in.

If you want to stick with ActiveState, and don't mind using a 3rd party repository of ppm packages, you can use this command to install a version of Net::SSH2 correctly compiled with libssh2:

```
ppm install http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppm/Net-SSH2.ppd
```

See this link on PerlMonks for a good explanation of the issue:

[Net-SSH2 on Windows with Perl 5.14](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=949926)

The OP in the above thread is using 5.14 but the sisyphusion ppd will detect your perl version and platform architecture.